# recyclerview not showing data from json array after 7 items

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-volley, targetsdkversion

I am using Recycler View with Cardview and showing data from JSON using Volley. It works proper on targetsdkversion 19 but not showing data after 7 list items when targetsdkversion is 26.

```
            btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    chatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subject = etsub.getText().toString();
                    details = etdetail.getText().toString();
                    if (etsub.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter subject", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        subj_layout.setError("Plese Enter Subject!");
                    }
                    else if (etdetail.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        detail_layout.setError("Please Enter Details!");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:send ");
                        String url = "http://webapi.eduware.in/test/api/ParentsCommunication?StudentCurrentID=" + studentId.trim() + "&SchoolID=" + schoolid.trim() + "&CommunicationSubject=" + subject.trim() + "&CommunicationDetails=" + details.trim();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + url);
                        Log.d(TAG, "fetchNotificationByVolley: url = " + url);

                        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                                            String status = jobj.getString("status");
                                            if (status.equals("1")) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                getChatbyVolley();
                                                txtnocomm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                chatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
                            }
                        }) {
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                return null;
                            }
                        };

                        ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
```

[As shown in image, on click of Bottom right corner Add Button One custom dialog gets open and details of that dislogs edittext will be added to recyclerview by getChatbyVolley method.I am getting succesfully added but not display in list.But if targetsdkversion is 18 then it works perfect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSX5Q.png)

```
private void getChatbyVolley() {
    chatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = "http://webapi.eduware.in/test/api/ParentsCommunication?StudentCurrentID="+studentId.trim();
    final ArrayList<Chat> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String status = jobj.getString("status");
                        if(status.equals("1"))
                        {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jobj.getJSONArray("data");

                            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String date = jsonObject.getString("Date");
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+date);
                                String[] separated = date.split("[T :]");
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: splitted string0" + separated[0]);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: splitted string1" + separated[1]);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: splitted string2" + separated[2]);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: splitted string3" + separated[3]);
                                String time = separated[1] + ":" + separated[2];
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: time is:::::::::::" + time);
                                DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
                                String inputDateStr=separated[0];
                                Date date1 = inputFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
                                String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(date1);
                                String detail = jsonObject.getString("CommunicationDetails");
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: details========="+detail);
                                String pid = jsonObject.getString("ParentID");
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: pid is*********"+pid);
                                array.add(pid);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: pid is*********"+array);
                                editor.putString("parent_id",pid);
                                editor.putString("parentid_array",array.toString());
                                editor.commit();
                                Chat c = new Chat();
                                c.setCommsubject(jsonObject.getString("CommunicationSubject"));
                                c.setCommdetails(jsonObject.getString("CommunicationDetails"));
                                c.setDate(outputDateStr);
                                c.setParentid(pid);
                                arrayList.add(c);
                                progress.dismiss();

                            }
                            chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + arrayList.size());
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No communication available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progress.dismiss();
                            rlnocomm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnadd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return null;
        }
    };
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this following line in your code. It works for me

```
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply....But still It is not working for me when targetsdkversion is 26 in build.gradle (App level) file.I can add new item to recyclerview but its not displaying anything after 7 items. Please help me if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: Send me your code to this email address. kbrahmaxatriya94@gmail.com

Comment: Use same Sdk version for all the dependencies try this compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+' or change the sdk version to 25

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and change parameter and inputtext  and Model Class as per your requirements

Its works for me...

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ProgressDialog pdialog;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
    private ArrayList<DataFarmer> dataFarmers;
    private ArrayList<Datum> datumArrayList;

    public Datum datum;
    NewInsuranceList newInsuranceList;

    Context context;
    BankInfo bankInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_my_insurance);
        context = this;
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initToolbar();
        doNormalPostOperation();
    }


    private void initToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public void doNormalPostOperation() {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pdialog.setMessage("Loading");
        pdialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "YOUR_URL",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        pdialog.dismiss();

                        Log.e("login output", response);

                        NewInsuranceListAll newInsuranceListAll = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response, NewInsuranceListAll.class);
                        datumArrayList = newInsuranceListAll.getDatumArrayList();
                        myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(datumArrayList);
                        recyclerview.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Something went Wrong.. Please Try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put("id", /*"1"*/PrefUtils.getUser(context).getData().get(0).getId());
                map.put("type", "get_insurance_list");
                Log.e("para", map + "");
                return map;
            }

        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Datum> moviesList;
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView farmer_name, aadhar_card, insurance_id, tagging_date, txtRepost;
            public ImageView farmer_image;
            CircleImageView circleImageViewProfile;
            ProgressBar simpleProgressBar;
            public Button btnViewMore;


            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                farmer_name = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_farmer_name);
                aadhar_card = view.findViewById(R.id.agent_adhar_number);
                insurance_id = view.findViewById(R.id.insurance_id);
                tagging_date = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_Tagging_Date);
                circleImageViewProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.visit_profile_image);
                btnViewMore = view.findViewById(R.id.btnViewMore);

            }

        }


        public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Datum> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_my_insurance, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        public void clear() {
            int size = this.moviesList.size();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    this.moviesList.remove(0);
                }

                this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final Datum datum = moviesList.get(position);

            holder.farmer_name.setText(datum.getFarmerName() + "  ");
            holder.aadhar_card.setText(datum.getFarmerAdhaar() + "  ");
            holder.insurance_id.setText(datum.getInsuranceNumber() + "  ");
            holder.tagging_date.setText(datum.getTaggingDate() + "  ");
            Picasso.with(MyInsuranceActivity.this).load("URL" + datum.getFarmerPhoto() + "").placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.circleImageViewProfile);

            holder.btnViewMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent viewMoreIntent = new Intent(context, ViewAllDetailsActivity.class);
                    viewMoreIntent.putExtra("farmer_id", moviesList.get(position).getFarmerId() + "");
                    Log.e("parasdasdas", moviesList.get(position).getFarmerId() + "");
                    startActivity(viewMoreIntent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }

    }
}
```